# Why are WebP utilities built on Ubuntu 14.04 not working and showing a library error?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, shared-library, webp

I've built **WebP utilities** on Ubuntu 14.04 following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compiling) found at the official website of WebP. As I've done everything successfully, my system should let me compress and decompress images using **cwebp** and **dwebp** utilities respectively. But, whenever I try to compress/decompress any image, the system gives me this error bellow,

```
cwebp: error while loading shared libraries: libwebp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I guess, [that page](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compiling) also describes my problem and solution to that as bellow,

> "The library will usually be installed under the /usr/local/lib/ directory. To avoid run-time errors, make sure that your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable includes this location."

I tried to add **`/usr/local/lib`** to my **`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`** environment variable in [this way](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-set-ld_library_path-684799/#3). But it's still giving me that error.

What should I do now?

However, I've also downloaded the prebuilt binaries from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-0.5.1-linux-x86-32.tar.gz). This binaries are working. But, for running those binaries, I've to go to the directory of that binaries or have to write **`path/to/the/binaries/./cwebp`** everytime. I'd also be helped, if I know how to install these prebuilt binaries on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the help of some members of [Full Circle Magazine](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/)'s official [Telegram group](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/2016/05/07/official-full-circle-telegram-group/), I've solved this problem successfully.

I've faced this problem, because my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable didn't include `/usr/local/lib`. To add `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, run the command bellow,

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

This will add the location `/usr/local/lib` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. To check that you've done this successfully, run this command,

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This command should show you this result, `:/usr/local/lib`

**NB:** You've to do this everytime after you've started a new **Terminal** session. If you don't want to do it again and again, run the command bellow,

```
$ echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will add a new line containing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` to the `.bashrc` file in the home directory.